# Java Server Non Blocking Query

Tags: java, client, blocking

I am using the following code to read some data from Android client. All is going fine. But now i am asked to make this server code non blocking. Is there any suggestions for this ? I was trying to use threads but dont know how ? I am beginner in Java :)

Thanks

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Server {
    //Server Constructor
    public Server()
    {}
    //Variables Initialization
    private static ServerSocket server;
    byte[] imagetemp;
    private static Socket socket1;
    private static boolean newImage;
    private static Sdfdata data;
    private static boolean cond;
    public static int port;
    private static int number = 0;
    //Image Availability return method
    public boolean imageAvailable()
    {
        return newImage;
    }
    public boolean clientchk()
    {
        return socket1.isClosed();
    }
    //Image Flag set by Vis group when image read.
    public void setImageFlag(boolean set)
    {
        newImage = set;
    }
    // Send the data to the Vis Group
    public Sdfdata getData()
    {
    return data;
    }
    //Starts the Server
    public static boolean start(int port1)
    {
        try {
            port=port1;

                server = new ServerSocket(port1);
            System.out.println("Waiting for Client to Connect");
            //New thread here 

            socket1=server.accept();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot Connect");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //Stops the Server
    public boolean stop() 
    {

        try {
            socket1.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Starts the server
        start(4444);
        // DataInput Stream for reading the data 
        DataInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(socket1.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        cond=true;

        do {

            try
            {
                //Read Image Data
                int length = in.readInt();
                //Create an ByteArray of length read from Client for Image transfer
                Sdfdata data = new Sdfdata(length);

                //for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
                //{ data.image[i] = in.readbyte();  }   

                if (length > 0) {
                    in.readFully(data.image);
                }

                //Read Orientation
                data.orientation[0] = in.readFloat();       //Orientation x
                data.orientation[1] = in.readFloat();       //Orientation y
                data.orientation[2] = in.readFloat();       //Orientation z

                //Read GPS
                data.longitude = in.readDouble();
                data.latitude = in.readDouble();
                data.altitude = in.readDouble();

                //Display orientation and GPS data
                System.out.println(data.orientation[0] + " " + data.orientation[1] + " " + data.orientation[2]);
                System.out.println(data.longitude + " " + data.latitude + " " + data.altitude);

                String fileName = "IMG_" + Integer.toString(++number) + ".JPG";
                System.out.println("FileName:  " + fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                fos.write(data.image);
                fos.close();





                /*InputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.image);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ins);
                ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File (fileName));
                */
                //set image flag
                newImage = true;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("EOF Or ? " + e);

                cond =false;
                socket1.close();
                server.close();
                start(port);

            }
    }while (cond);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code starts a server, waits for a connection, reads some data from the first connected client, and then exits after writing this data to a file.

Being asked to make your server "non-blocking" could mean that you are being asked to change it to use asynchronous IO (probably unlikely), or it could mean that you're being asked to handle more than one client at a time - because currently you can only serve one client and then your program exits.

This question is hard to answer because your current code is very far away from where you need it to be and it seems like some reading up on networking, sockets, and Java programming in general would be a good way to start.

I'd recommend [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) for doing anything network-related in Java and their samples and documentation are good and easy to follow.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Alpine. No, I am not asked to us asynchronous IO. I am just asked to start a thread that should listen on the socket instead of this socket listening. It will be only one thread and would help to minimize CPU usage or so. If i am in correct way.